# have using opencv detect object in image floor plan to use

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, image-processing

I'm having trouble using OpenCV of iOS, I want to use this tool to detect objects on the planning of the event.

What to choose is arrested Booth (General squares, rectangles metric), doors, tables, chairs, etc., any atmosphere.

I do not know how to start.
 You can advise or help me a favor. I'll take it to the subject in class.

this project I can't adapt to the detect matrix square
github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares

Some photo input :

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zhsrpti4bzxwctq/AADrZ-P5oRO2Vg6G4PRNqKsJa?dl=0

This is the model I've ever made. When the position, size, form of the objects in the image.

https://youtu.be/ecPHou-E82g

Comment: "I have tried and failed" won't give you any useful answers... It is not even clear what you want to do and you did not provide any information on how you tried to achieve whatever it is you want to achieve. 
Provide your code and some example image with annotations and desired output...

Comment: https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares This project, adapt detect matrix square this project detect only square, I want this detect object in image floor plan some door, boots, etc. 

So sorryม I may not be meaningful. I am not good at English